# multiple select is not working at all on chrome

Tags: html, select

I'm having some weird issues.

I need a multiple select with some values in it, but somehow if I type 
multiple and size values to select tag they are not working.

For that I decided to make a new clear file to test it and the result is same.

```
  <form action="" method="post">

<select name="data[]" multiple size="5">

    <option value="1">1Value</option>
    <option value="2">2Value</option>
    <option value="3">3Value</option>
    <option value="4">4Value</option>
    <option value="4">4Value</option>
    <option value="4">4Value</option>
    <option value="4">4Value</option>

</select>

</form>
```

These are my codes, and this is below is the result:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vI9sj.png)

I can't even select them one by one, I mean browser is not highlighting the ones that I selected, I need to hold CTRL to hightlight them, as like working on windows I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: Is that your complete code? If so then you're missing the select tag

Comment: I tried using multiple & size and it seems to work on chrome. https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FVKZSYMIF376

Comment: "i need to hold CTRL to hightlight them" , that seems to be the behaviour when "multiple" options are to be selected Or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you bind it inside select tags?, you have to.

```
<select name="values" multiple>
 <option value="1">value1</option>
 <option value="2">value2</option>
 <option value="3">value3</option>
 <option value="4">value4</option>
</select>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for you time mate, but it is alredy in select tags i think i missed to copy them while copy/paste

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you have installed some Chrome extension that is preventing the Ctrl key to work as expected. Try removing that.

Answer (score 1):

Please go with HTML  multiple Attribute.

Try Below code:

```
 <select name="Custom_Name" multiple>
    <option value="1">1Value</option>
    <option value="2">2Value</option>
    <option value="3">3Value</option>
    <option value="4">4Value</option>
    <option value="4">4Value</option>
    <option value="4">4Value</option>
    <option value="4">4Value</option>
```

Al the best.